# How to use FULLTEXT index in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, full-text-search, pdo

Suppose that I have two tables `stuff` and `search_index`. For various reasons I would prefer to generate a custom index table with schema along the lines of the following.

I believe that this has to be a separate table as it would require `MyISAM` storage engine for FULLTEXT support. All of my other tables are `InnoDB` for transaction support.

```
search_index (MyISAM):
-----------------------
stuff_id    BIGINT    PRIMARY
keywords    TEXT      FULLTEXT  ; Not same as text in `stuff`
                                ; (optimised & space delimited)
```

How often should `search_index` table be updated:

1. Whenever `stuff` records are created or updated.
2. Periodically scan "dirty" `stuff` records and update `search_index` accordingly.
3. Other...

My view is that the benefit of **1** would be easier to maintain and search becomes effective immediately but with an immediate re-index in database. **2** would not be as effective but all reindexing can happen in one hit. Is this true?

How efficient is MySQL at inserting/updating records that have FULLTEXT indexing?

*Additional Note: I am trying to keep the schema as portable as possible (different rdbms drivers with PDO)*

Comment: Do #1, and when you actually run into a performance problem / resource limitation, implement #2.